# Retain GridBagLayout component order?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I have problems with GridBagLayout. I have to replace a component but after inserting the new one the positions change. See the following code as example. 
At the start it is CYAN and YELLOW (from left to the right). After replacing it is YELLOW and RED. My desired result is RED and YELLOW. How can I fix this (with GridBagLayout)?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GBLTest extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new GBLTest();
    }

    JPanel panelA;
    JPanel panelB;
    JPanel panelAReplacement;

    GBLTest()
    {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
        cons.weightx = 1.0;
        cons.weighty = 1.0;
        cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        panelA = new JPanel();
        panelA.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        panelB = new JPanel();
        panelB.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        panelAReplacement = new JPanel();
        panelAReplacement.setBackground(Color.RED);


        cons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        this.add(panelA, cons);
        cons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        this.add(panelB, cons);

        GridBagConstraints oldCons = ((GridBagLayout) this.getContentPane().getLayout()).getConstraints(panelA);
        this.remove(panelA);
        this.add(panelAReplacement, oldCons);

        this.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the java tag, otherwise the question might not be looked at by the right people ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the correct Layout for this pourpose.
You should use BorderLayout instead GridBagLayout. Or use the gridx and gridy properties to set the cell where each panel should be allocated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GBLTest extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new GBLTest();
    }

    JPanel panelA;
    JPanel panelB;
    JPanel panelAReplacement;

    GBLTest()
    {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints consA = new GridBagConstraints();
        consA.weightx = 1.0;
        consA.weighty = 1.0;
        consA.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        consA.gridx = 0;
        consA.gridy = 0;

        GridBagConstraints consB = new GridBagConstraints();
        consB.weightx = 1.0;
        consB.weighty = 1.0;
        consB.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        consB.gridx = 1;
        consB.gridy = 0;

        panelA = new JPanel();
        panelA.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        panelB = new JPanel();
        panelB.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        panelAReplacement = new JPanel();
        panelAReplacement.setBackground(Color.RED);


        consA.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        this.add(panelA, consA);
        consA.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        this.add(panelB, consB);

        GridBagConstraints oldCons = ((GridBagLayout)     this.getContentPane().getLayout()).getConstraints(panelA);
        this.remove(panelA);
        this.add(panelAReplacement, oldCons);

        this.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, going the way with GBL using the grid constraints, if I set the preferredSize for the panelAReplacement it doesn't effect the GUI. Is it possible to use your solution with the grid but use the preferredSize of the components (with GBL)?
I know that I can use the weightx to solve this issue but I don't know a fixed value for the weightx because I want to use the preferred one which is dynamically calculated... :(